# Why isn't my ModelState error showing on the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I did the things per [this answer here][1] regarding ModelState and errors, but I think I'm missing something since I'm still not seeing the error on my page.

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

// GET: User
[HttpGet]
[Route("Create/{token}", Name = "Create")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(string token)
{
    try
    {
        if (TempData["err"] != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", TempData["err"] as Exception);
            TempData.Clear();
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            token = "foobar"; // For testing to force an error.
            var municipality = await db.Municipalities.SingleAsync(x => x.OneOffToken == token);
            return View(municipality);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["err"] = ex;
        return View();
    }
}
```

This adds the model error to the ModelState as expected, but how exactly do I get the error to show on my View? When I test the page, I see no indication that anything went wrong except for there's absolutely nothing on the view (as intended though an error message would be nice though).

Comment: Do you have any `ValidationMessageFor`s in the view?

Comment: Or a ValidationSummary.  https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-validationmessagefor

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment on the question by Steve Greene, I used a ValidationSummary on the view to show a custom error.

This involved adding the ValidationSummary to the view:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

And a slight change to the backend logic to actually put the Exception's `message` into the ModelState:

```
if (TempData["err"] != null) {
    // Cast the object in TempData to an exception.
    var ex = TempData["err"] as Exception;

    // Add to ModelState.
    ModelState.AddModelError("err", ex.Message);

    // Clear TempData so we don't get stuck here.
    TempData.Clear();

    return View();
}
else {
    // There's no error so normal page initialization can go here.
}
```

It's worth noting that the `catch` should `RedirectToAction` after it sets TempData that's because the View returned won't have the ModelError in it's ModelState so to get the error to display, you'd actually have to refresh the page manually after it occurs.